# Insert datos php5.6 => sql server

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Mira tengo un script para insertar datos pero no funciona correctamente y no muestra errores pero no guarda, mi codigo :

```
<?php
require('conexion.php');

                $cliente = filter_var(strtolower($_POST['cliente']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
                $calle = filter_var(strtolower($_POST['calle']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
                $numero = filter_var(strtolower($_POST['numero']), FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
                $Ttel = filter_var(strtolower($_POST['Ttel']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
                $ciudad = filter_var(strtolower($_POST['ciudad']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
                $rfc = filter_var(strtolower($_POST['rfc']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
                $estado = filter_var(strtolower($_POST['estado']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
                $cp = filter_var(strtolower($_POST['cp']), FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
                $email = filter_var(strtolower($_POST['email']), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
                $Tcliente = filter_var(strtolower($_POST['Tcliente']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);



        $insertar="INSERT into CatClientes(C_Nombre, C_Direccion, C_Numero, C_RFC, C_Cp)VALUES('$cliente','$calle','$numero','$rfc','$cp')";
        $insertardos="INSERT into CatCiudades(Cd_Descripcion)VALUES ('$ciudad')";
        $insertartres="INSERT into CatClientesEmails(Mail_Descripcion)VALUES('$email')";

        $consulta = "$insertar"."$insertardos"."$insertartres";
echo $consulta;
$stmtdos = sqlsrv_query($conn, $consulta);
var_dump($consulta);
//header("location:index2.php");


?>
```

Hice un var dump a lo que estaba enviando y salio esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y bien este query lo meti en el sql server y me salio esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si esta mal el query o que onda, me podrian ayudar, saludos

Creo que uno es que no puedo dejar nulos dos columnas, es algo que esta en proceso pero el otro error? no comprendo, también observo que el query se ejecuta dos veces en la web, es normal?

Comment: Intenta agregar ; al final de cada insert. Tambien puedes intentar correr cada query individualmente.

Comment: Tienes varios problemas de diseño. Se tiene que dar un paso hacia atrás en todo esto. Estás insertando filas en 3 tablas distintas sin establecer una relación entre las mismas. Alguna columna de CatClientes (tal vez C_nombre) es demasiado pequeña para guardar el valor completo que le mandas. No estás enviando suficientes valores en la tabla CatClientesEmails. Al final, debería ser un Procedimiento Almacenado que guarde todo en una sola transacción, pero no hay suficiente información para realizarlo.

Answer (score 2):

Los mensajes son claros, donde te dice string or binary truncated, es porque el tamaño de tus datos es mayor a los que puede guardar la base de datos, revisa su tamaño en la tabla que estás guardando y amplía el número de caracteres permitidos.

Los otros dos mensajes es porque estás insertando datos, pero tus tablas requieren esos datos que te solicitan, en MIDAS.dbo.CatCiudades el campo Cd_Id seguramente es tu Id y no lo tienes autoincrementable, por eso te marca error, mientras que en la tabla MIDAS.dbo.CatClientesEmails el campo C_Centro no puede ser null, y como no le envías nada te marca error, sino requieres ese campo, prueba a cambiar su tipo en la tabla de NOT NULL a NULL (de no permitir nulos a sí permitirlos)

Saludos, espero te ayude.